# Swift Atomic Property dead lock issue

Tags: swift

Here is our AtomicProperty.swift class.

```
class AtomicProperty<T> {
    private var _property: T?
    var property: T? {
        get {
            var retVal: T?
            lock.sync {
                retVal = _property
            }
            return retVal
        }
        set {
            lock.async(flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags.barrier) {
                self._property = newValue
            }
        }
    }
    private let lock: DispatchQueue = {
        var name = "AtomicProperty" + String(Int.random(in: 0...100000))
        let clzzName = String(describing: T.self)
        name += clzzName
        return DispatchQueue(label: name, attributes: .concurrent)
    }()

    init(property: T) {
        self.property = property
    }

    init() {

    }
    
    // perform an atomic operation on the atomic property
    // the operation will not run if the property is nil.
    public func performAtomic(atomicOperation: ((_ prop:inout T) -> Void)) {
        lock.sync(flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags.barrier) {
            if var prop = _property {
                atomicOperation(&prop)
                _property = prop
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Normally this it is working fine. Here is a sample test case which causes dead lock issue.

```
func test_atomicPropertyDeadlocks() async {
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
    let expectations = (0..<80).map { id in
        let expectation = expectation(description: "Queue Test \(id)")
        operationQueue.addOperation {
            self.subject.property = (self.subject.property ?? 0) + 1
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
            self.subject.property = (self.subject.property ?? 0) + 1
            expectation.fulfill()
        }
        return expectation
    }

    let finalExpectation = expectation(description: "Final")
    operationQueue.addBarrierBlock {
        finalExpectation.fulfill()
    }

    await fulfillment(of: expectations + CollectionOfOne(finalExpectation), timeout: 10.0)

    self.subject.property = 0
}
```

Can someone please explain what is the potential cause and how can I solve this?

When the expectation loop count is small it passes successfully. But when the loop is about 64 or more then the deadlock issue arises.

Comment: Why not use an `actor` is you need thread safe mutable variables?